# How to get all matches for a String with RegEx and Mutated Vowels - Hastags

Tags: javascript, regex, web, unicode

I am looking for a way to replace all of these hashtags with something else:

> #foo #foo #foo

Currently I use this code:

```
msg = msg.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)#' + searchString + '(\\s|$)', 'gi'), $1 + 'bar' + $2");
```

This solution works as long as there is only two times the same hashtag but as soon as it becomes three or more, it fails.

A simple approch is as far I know not possible because I need to support Mutated Vowels (unicode) and I have to replace all occurences at once.

So I am looking for a regular expression which can handle more than two times the same hashtag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex with lookahead to fix this issue:

```
msg = msg.replace(new RegExp('#' + searchString + '(?=\\s|$)', 'gi'), '#bar');
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQ6eD4/1)

You regex is also **consuming space** after matched string leaving no space to be matched for next occurrence of match.

**Update:** If you really want to match optional space before `#` then you can use:

```
msg = msg.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)#' + searchString + '(?=\\s|$)', 'gi'), "$1" + 'bar');
```